# Error while install wifi driver (rtl8188CUS)

Tags: wireless

I have purchased the EDUP wifi dongle from Amazon. which has `RTL8188CUS` drivers. I have downloaded the zip file (using my windows machine) and then transferred it to the UP board using usb flash drive. I extracted the zip file on the desktop, which contains the `install.sh` file. to install the drivers on my UPboard, I used the command `sh install.sh` but I am getting the errors and not able to install the wifi drivers.

```
makefile:150: recipe for target 'sub make' failed
make[2]:***[sub-make]error-2 ................................
.........................
############################### compile make driver error:2 please check error mesg
###############################
```

please help. Thanks a lot.
when I type `lsusb` it shows me

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter
```

but when I enter the code `lsmod | grep rtl` it doesn't give me any result.
I was also following the following link

> https://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=40015https://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=40015

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you running?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `sudo modprobe rtl8192cu` and also: `uname -r`